# Why does one javascript "pause" when another changes image?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hej guys,

I have two javascripts on page called main.php that is included into index.php.

The first script scrolls between 3 images, with 4 seconds delay.

The second script scrolls 10 images vertically without pauses, it keeps going so to speak.

My question is: Why does the vertical scroller "pause" or stop for half a second when the other script is about to change image?

I can show you code if you need, but I was hoping for an easy answer. I'm not very skilled when it comes to javascript.

Everything can be shown on www-seorapport-se. (Site is not supposed to be indexed).

Thank you for your help and understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because javascript is blocking (synchronous). For example:

```
alert('a');
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000000000000000000000000; i++) {
    // do nothing
}
alert('b');
```

It'll first show you `a`, after you close that dialog it'll start the for-loop, which will take some time. After `i = 1000000000000000000000000000000`, it'll show you `b`.

You are using *2* scripts, but the idea is the same since most (if not all) browsers are performing the scripts on the same thread, so it's still blocking.

Comment: Can I implent this code into main.php to make them independent of eachother? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jaoza this is only an example to show you that javascript-code is blocking.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Is there an easy way for me to fix this? Maybe there's a command a little like the jQuery NoConflict that prevents the scripts from blocking eachother?

Comment: NoConflict is totally different from this. NoConflict prevents jQuery to assign values to globals that are also used by MooTools and stuff. I'm not aware of any workaround ...

Comment: **Update:** if you're using a browser that supports HTML5, you can add the "async"-param to your script-elm (`<script async>...</script>`). Else, you can look at this page for a workaround: http://www.xul.fr/javascript/asynchronous.php